# Echarts Bar Chart Axis Label on Top and Bottom

Tags: data-visualization, formatter, echarts

I would like to display labels on the top x-axis and bottom x-axis in my bar charts. I am trying to express the bar as a range between two opposing values, for example: Energetic vs Laid Back.

Does anyone know how to do this in `echarts`? Ideally it would be something like below, but I haven't been able to find anything:

```
option = {
  ...

  xAxis: [{
    type: "category",
    data-top: ["happy", "energetic", "early-bird"],
    data-bottom: ["melancholy", "laid-back", "night-owl"]
  }],

  ...
}
```

I would expect there to be a way to do it with the `formatter` option, but I have no idea how.

Your help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use secondary x-axis to display labels on top and bottom of the chart

Please refer the chart option below,

```
option = {
    xAxis: [{
        type: 'category',
        data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
    },
    {
        type: 'category',
        data: ['Mon Top', 'Tue Top', 'Wed Top', 'Thu Top', 
        'Fri Top', 'Sat Top', 'Sun Top']
    }],
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [120, 200, 150, 80, 70, 110, 130],
        type: 'bar',
        showBackground: true,
        backgroundStyle: {
            color: 'rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.8)'
        }
    }]
};
```

The chart should displayed as,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In ECharts v5 you can use the `position` attribute for `top` and `bottom`. When doing so, be sure to set the `min` and `max` values the same and hide `splitLine` on one axis.

Example:

```
xAxis: [
  {
    type: 'value',
    position: 'top',
    min: 0,
    max: 1000,
  },
  {
    type: 'value',
    position: 'bottom',
    min: 0,
    max: 1000,
    splitLine: {
      show: false,
    },
  },
]
```